# Virtual Keyboard for MooTools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard, mootools

Is there something like this [Virtual Keyboard](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/), but utilizing MooTools as the underlying library rather than jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: ran across this right here. http://crew.tweakers.net/NMe/prg/tobo/index.html but this uses mootools 1.2

Comment: @kjy112 that looks promising - very lightweight!

Comment: @kjy112 Very cool, should work fine with the latest version of mootools as long as compatibility mode is included with the build.

Comment: 2011 - development by Jeroen van den Broek - this is the guy that develop it.  i just found it online.

Answer (score 3):

try this one: https://github.com/fabiomcosta/mootools-meio-virtualkeyboard